# uncaught typeError: cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, navigation, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to use this menu for mobile on a site. 
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/13/multi-level-push-menu/comment-page-8/#comment-466199

I have it working but one ie11 user is reporting an error and i am seeing the following error in console 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of nullmlPushMenu._init @ mlpushmenu.js:89mlPushMenu @ mlpushmenu.js:67(anonymous function) @ (index):1062

Here is a snippet of the js file in question

```js
function mlPushMenu( el, trigger, options ) {   
    this.el = el;
    this.trigger = trigger;
    this.options = extend( this.defaults, options );
    // support 3d transforms
    this.support = Modernizr.csstransforms3d;
    if( this.support ) {
        this._init();
    }
}

mlPushMenu.prototype = {
    defaults : {
        // overlap: there will be a gap between open levels
        // cover: the open levels will be on top of any previous open level
        type : 'overlap', // overlap || cover
        // space between each overlaped level
        levelSpacing : 40,
        // classname for the element (if any) that when clicked closes the current level
        backClass : 'mp-back'
    },
    _init : function() {
        // if menu is open or not
        this.open = false;
        // level depth
        this.level = 0;
        // the moving wrapper
        this.wrapper = document.getElementById( 'mp-pusher' );
        // the mp-level elements
        this.levels = Array.prototype.slice.call( this.el.querySelectorAll( 'div.mp-level' ) );
        // save the depth of each of these mp-level elements
        var self = this;
        this.levels.forEach( function( el, i ) { el.setAttribute( 'data-level', getLevelDepth( el, self.el.id, 'mp-level' ) ); } );
        // the menu items
        this.menuItems = Array.prototype.slice.call( this.el.querySelectorAll( 'li' ) );
        // if type == "cover" these will serve as hooks to move back to the previous level
        this.levelBack = Array.prototype.slice.call( this.el.querySelectorAll( '.' + this.options.backClass ) );
        // event type (if mobile use touch events)
        this.eventtype = mobilecheck() ? 'touchstart' : 'click';
        // add the class mp-overlap or mp-cover to the main element depending on options.type
        classie.add( this.el, 'mp-' + this.options.type );
        // initialize / bind the necessary events
        this._initEvents();
    },
```

the specific line 89 is in the middle of that so here it is pulled out for your orientation

```
this.levels = Array.prototype.slice.call( this.el.querySelectorAll( 'div.mp-level' ) );
```

I have then called the instance of the plugin in my footer (thats the index line 1082

that call looks like this

```
<script>
    new mlPushMenu(
        document.getElementById( 'mp-menu' ),
        document.getElementById( 'trigger' ),
        { type : 'cover' }
    );
</script>
```

Comment: You're positive `#mp-menu` exists when `new mlPushMenu` is invoked, correct? Also, which document mode is Internet Explorer in? You can easily determine this by pressing F12 and noting the selected mode in the Emulation panel, or inserting `document.documentMode` into the console. I suspect the issue is that the element has not yet been created, or IE has slipped into an earlier mode that doesn't support querySelectorAll.

Comment: Actually its the opposite direction. When i run ie in edge, and 10 it throws the error in console. When i run in 9 or lower it does not. In 8 or lower however it does show the mobile menu. I have the new mlPushMenu  script in the footer it should exist already. You will have to forgive my ignorance, JS is not my wheelhouse.

Comment: Can you put your page online someplace for direct access? Or, better yet, upload a demo/example to a URL that will not soon change (for the sake of others who may come across this question in the future).

Comment: So the site is currently here http://proficientrx.com/ and it should stay for at least a year or so. You will have to fogive the code. the site is a real hack job but i am new at this so go easy on me.   I have narrowed it down to only in I.E. 7 and below. Now i just need to talk the client into ignoring the issue.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. You have narrowed it down to IE7 and below? That means you no longer have an issue in Internet Explorer 8, 9, 10, or 11 (or Microsoft Edge)?

Comment: Would it help if i just stuck in a meta to force the browser to run in edge mode? Something like <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge" >. The JS error is still there in all modes but it only presents a problem in i.e.7 mode and below so far as i can tell.

Comment: You don't have an `#mp-menu` element on this page. So `document.getElementById` returns `null`. The `x-ua-compat` header/tag *will not* fix this problem, since the problem isn't a document mode issue, but rather a missing element issue.

Comment: Yeah i see that the meta would really only bandaid the display issue. in my header i do have the mobile menu with an id of mp-menu but this menu is only called if you are looking at the site on mobile. you can see this if you load it in the chrome user agent as a mobile device. I think the problem is that the browser doesn't see the menu because it is not called by the php in desktop mode. So if i moved my new mlPush into an else if statement that might fix it. Will try not and post results

Comment: The meta tag is unrelated to anything I'm seeing in Internet Explorer 11. You need to *only* load this JavaScript when on the mobile site. The script is attempting to locate an element that is *only present on the mobile site*.

Comment: Yup, I see what you are saying. So what i did was not call any of the JS files unless the mobile_detect picks it up and that solved it. Now the error is gone. thank you very much for all of your help Johnathan. You are great! :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your desktop site does not have an element with an ID of "*mp-menu*." When you call the *getElementById* method, you're getting `null` in response. This is then assigned to the `el` property of the object. When you attempt to call *querySelectorAll*, you're attempting to do so from a null value.

According to the comments on the question above, the *mp-menu* element is present on the *mobile site* alone. If this is the case, this code should also *only be loaded on mobile*.

Comment: This is exactly the answer, yes!.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the JS files were being called on all platforms, desktop and mobile. while the mobile menu that used the mlPushMenu was only called on mobile devices. making it so the JS files were only called on mobile solved the problem for desktop browsers.